# Inserting a record in BigQuery table via windows service

Tags: .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, windows-services, google-bigquery

I've created a windows service that communicates with the Google BigQuery API perfectly using Service Account authorization. For testing purposes, I'm able to fetch data from a BigQuery table to check communication between my Windows service and the BigQuery API. But this service will basically fetch records from MSSQL server and then one by one will insert or append a record to the target table in BigQuery. I don't want to use CSV or JSON files as a data source. Is there any way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to use either CSV or JSON as a source format to load your data into BigQuery.

BigQuery currently supports a batch ingestion model, not a record level model. The daily import quota is 1,000 import jobs per table and 10,000 import jobs total for the whole project.

I would suggest that you export data out of MSSQL server in intervals (perhaps hourly), cache the output in a CSV or JSON file, and then kick off a BigQuery ingestion job after the MSSQL export step is complete.

Comment: So, I can run this BigQuery ingestion job over CSV or JSON files that are stored on local disks or will have to first upload these files to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: It's possible to directly post files to the BigQuery API, but in general I suggest first uploading the data to Cloud Storage. For more information, I suggest reading the documentation about this: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#import

Comment: Again a new problem arose:- Is there any programmatical(i.e in .net) way of uploading locally stored CSV files to Google Cloud Storage? Also, For uploading locally stored CSV file's data to Big Query table, will i have to call already created job from Big Query and then recreate the body for that job with appended csv file's data and then make request or directly pass job's body with appended csv file's data to 'bigquery.job.insert()' method? if so then how to pass jobs body to Big Query object. I'm trying this process but not getting any result yet. Please help me out. Thanks