# Insert 1 million records from SQL Server to BigQuery table, linked via CDATA odbc driver

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, odbc, google-bigquery

I need to insert 1 million (and more) records from a SQL Server table to a BigQuery table, that is present in SQL Server as "linked server" via [CDATA odbc driver](http://www.cdata.com/hotfix/DBDA-A_5778_demo.exe) with remoting daemon in it [(documentation)](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DBA/odbc/pg_insertselect.htm).

Also, source table might have no column with number of row, Id etc.

For now, I can insert **1 record per second** into BigQuery with this driver, using this query:

```
INSERT INTO [GBQ].[CDataGoogleBigQuery].[GoogleBigQuery].[natality]
    SELECT * 
    FROM [natality].[dbo].[natality] 
GO
```

But for such a bunch of records, as 1 Million or more, it's an EXTREMELY LOW performance.

I believe there's a workaround, that can allow me to speed up insertion process. Thanks in advance, comrades.

Answer (score 1):

Create an SSIS package to perform a fast load from the `[natality].[dbo].[natality] table to [GBQ].[CDataGoogleBigQuery].[GoogleBigQuery].[natality] table`.  In short, fast load is used in ETL process to bulk load.

High level how to:

1. In SSIS, select a data flow task from the Toolbox.
2. Click on the data flow task and select edit.
3. On the Data Flow page, select from
   the tool box your ole db source and ole db destination.  Link the 2 tasks together.
4. Set up your ole db source connection for `[natality].[dbo].[natality]`.
5. Set up your ole db destination for `[GBQ].[CDataGoogleBigQuery].[GoogleBigQuery].[natality]`.  Be sure the fast load to table setting is selected.

Once your done, execute the package.

Comment: does this internally do a single batch upload to bigquery?

Comment: I did, as you mentioned, and, unfortunally, nothing's changed: it still loads 1 record per second. Any ideas?

Comment: i dont know about linking bigtable like that so sorry if im off base. i do know well the bigquery api and normally what you would do is upload a single file to bigquery which contains all the rows you want to insert in your table (then wait for job to finish if you require to know when it finished). its little code to write once you get past the authorization (oauth2) part.

Comment: Found a possible answer on another stackoverflow question pertaining to your question. Not sure if you tried the approach yet.  Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133693/inserting-a-record-in-bigquery-table-via-windows-service Also, here is a link to the Google Cloud page I believe the person answering the question referenced.  Link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery

Comment: @ZigMandel As CDATA support just wrote me, it can be done pretty fast with this baby [this](http://www.cdata.com/hotfix/DBSA-A_5781_demo.exe) and this [documentation](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DBA/rssis/pg_toolboxr.htm)

Comment: I'm inserting now 2,7 million records (387 Mb) table from MS SQL to BQ via CDATA SSIS. As soon, as it'd be completed, I'll post a results here.

Answer (score 0):

The link in @Blasterdick comment is no longer available, but the latest build from CData's website works: http://www.cdata.com/drivers/bigquery/ssis

BatchMode is the name of the property that controls Bulk queries, and is enabled by default.