# load data from on prem sql server to bigquery using SSIS

Tags: google-bigquery

i setup the VPN connection between my on-prem sql server and GCP. i need to load more than 10 million rows data from sql server to bigquery. is there any way to achieve it? can i use SSIS to load the data to bigquery?

my team lead request to use dataflow to load the data to bigquery and not using SSIS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert 1 million records from SQL Server to BigQuery table, linked via CDATA odbc driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33421470/insert-1-million-records-from-sql-server-to-bigquery-table-linked-via-cdata-odb)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to using SSIS to load the data from the on-premises SQL Server to BigQuery, [this](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/bigquery-ssis-task-export-2008.rst) might be what you're looking for. As for using Cloud Dataflow, the official GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/performing-etl-from-relational-database-into-bigquery) details how it can be done, although you might need to use Cloud Storage as an intermediate data sink.